# Marginalising out $B$ in $P(A \mid B,C)$

Tags: probability

Let's say that I have $P(A \mid B,C)$ - is it accurate to say that $P(A \mid C)$ can be found like this:

$P(A \mid C) = \sum_B P(A \mid B,C)$

I know the values of all $P(A \mid B,C)$ as well as $P(B)$ and $P(C)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably know (marginalization, or total probability)

$$P(A) = \sum_B P(A,B)$$

Because this is true for any $A,B$, it's also true for the variables conditioned on $C$ (which amounts to restricting the universe).

$$P(A \mid C) = \sum_B P(A,B\mid C)$$

Further $P(A,B\mid C)=P(A \mid B,C)P(B\mid C)$.

(Why? Because $P(A,B)=P(A \mid B) P(B)$; again, that must be also true if conditioning everything over $C$).

Hence

$$P(A \mid C) =\sum_B P(A \mid B,C)P(B\mid C)$$

Answer (score 2):

It should be $P(A|C)=\sum_B P(A|B,C)P(B|C)$.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how this is derived?

Comment: That is the Law of Total Probability  (Also, assumes all parts, $B$, are independent of $C$.)

Comment: The last factor should be $P(B|C)$

Answer (score 1):

> is it accurate to say that $P(A \mid C)$ can be found like this:
>
> $$P(A \mid C) = \sum_B P(A \mid B,C)$$

Not *quite*.

By the Law of Total Probability ( and definition of Conditional Probability), we have: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid C) & = \sum_{B\in\{B_i\}} \mathsf P(A, B\mid C)
\\[1ex] & = \sum_{B\in\{B_i\}} \mathsf P(A\mid B, C)~\mathsf P(B\mid C)
\end{align}$$

Where the set, $\{B_i\}$, partitions the probability space .